# T-SQL, show a set of rows (specific column) as a field, for a better desc, please see the table relationship

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, select

I have been having a problem for quite a while now, that I can show with a sample of 5 tables (I'm actually dealing with more than 5!):

```
--------------------------------
shipments                       |
--------------------------------
idShipment | idRoute | idClient |
1          | 1       |     1    |
2          | 2       |     1    |
3          | 2       |     2    |
---------------------------------

-----------------------------------------
routes                                   |
-----------------------------------------
idRoute    | shortNameRoute |    name    |
1          | ACA            |  ACAPULCO  |
2          | MTY            |  MONTERREY |
-----------------------------------------

-------------------------
points                   |
-------------------------
idPoint    | PointName   |
1          | ACAPULCO    |
2          | ACAPULCO_2  |
3          | MONTERREY   |   
4          | MONTERREY_2 | 
--------------------------

-------------------------
clients                  |
-------------------------
idClient   | ClientName  |
1          | Mocosoft    |
2          | Mapple      |
--------------------------



 /*This table has the relationship between routes and points*/
--------------------------------
routePoints                     |
--------------------------------
idRoutePoint | idRoute | idPoint|
1            |   1     |   1    |
2            |   1     |   2    |
3            |   2     |   3    |
4            |   2     |   4    |
--------------------------------
```

How can I get the "point name(s)" for a route as a field in a result set?  For example:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
result                                                          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
idShipment | shortNameRoute | points                 | client   |
1          | ACA            | ACAPULCO,ACAPULCO_2    | Mocosoft |
2          | MTY            | MONTERREY,MONTERREY_2  | Mapple   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

To date I have been using .Net code to process the points by route.  I imagine there is a more efficient way to do this with T-SQL.

Perhaps I need to "normalize" my database more efficiently?

I don't like performing a query request for every shipment, along with extra loops in my code, but until now, it's the only way and I'm kind of lost.

I expect the solution might involve something like PIVOT, SELECT nested or probably "WITH" Common Table Expressions, but, I'm not sure.

Note: I'm using SQLServer 2008 R2

Here is the script to create the DB with Data example (TEST_ROUTES)

```
USE [TEST_ROUTES]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[shipments]
(
    [idShipment] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [idRoute] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idClient] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_shipments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idShipment] ASC
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[shipments] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[shipments] ([idShipment], [idRoute], [idClient]) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT [dbo].[shipments] ([idShipment], [idRoute], [idClient]) VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT [dbo].[shipments] ([idShipment], [idRoute], [idClient]) VALUES (3, 2, 2);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[shipments] OFF;


SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[routes]
(
    [idRoute] [int] NOT NULL,
    [shortNameRoute] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [routeName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_routes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idRoute] ASC
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO
INSERT [dbo].[routes] ([idRoute], [shortNameRoute], [routeName]) VALUES (1, N'ACA', N'ACAPULCO');
INSERT [dbo].[routes] ([idRoute], [shortNameRoute], [routeName]) VALUES (2, N'MTY', N'MONTERREY');

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[routePoints]
(
    [idRoutePoints] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idRoute] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idPoint] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_routePoints] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idRoutePoints] ASC
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

INSERT [dbo].[routePoints] ([idRoutePoints], [idRoute], [idPoint]) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT [dbo].[routePoints] ([idRoutePoints], [idRoute], [idPoint]) VALUES (2, 1, 2);
INSERT [dbo].[routePoints] ([idRoutePoints], [idRoute], [idPoint]) VALUES (3, 2, 3);
INSERT [dbo].[routePoints] ([idRoutePoints], [idRoute], [idPoint]) VALUES (4, 2, 4);

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[points](
    [idPoint] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PointName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_points] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idPoint] ASC
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[points] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[points] ([idPoint], [PointName]) VALUES (1, N'ACAPULCO');
INSERT [dbo].[points] ([idPoint], [PointName]) VALUES (2, N'ACAPULCO_2');
INSERT [dbo].[points] ([idPoint], [PointName]) VALUES (3, N'MONTERREY');
INSERT [dbo].[points] ([idPoint], [PointName]) VALUES (4, N'MONTERREY_2');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[points] OFF;


SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[clients]
(
    [idClient] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [clientName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_clients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [idClient] ASC
    ) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX  = OFF
        , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF
        , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
        , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[clients] ON;

INSERT [dbo].[clients] ([idClient], [clientName]) VALUES (1, N'Mapple');
INSERT [dbo].[clients] ([idClient], [clientName]) VALUES (2, N'Mocosoft');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[clients] OFF;
```

Comment: Your question would be substantially improved (and easier to answer) if you replaced your text outline of the tables with DDL scripts to create the tables. Bonus votes for including scripts to insert sample data.

Comment: It's done Mark, thanks for the tip, and sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a (crude) hack in SQL Server to do group_concats that should get what you need, below is a query for your example. I can't vouch for its performance so you will need to test/optimise as required.

```
select idshipment, shortnameroute,
(   
    select pointname +', ' 
    from points p
    inner join routepoints rp on rp.idpoint = p.idpoint
    where rp.idroute = r.idroute  for XML path ('')
), 
c.clientname
from shipments s
inner join [routes] r on r.idroute = s.idroute
inner join clients c on c.idclient = s.idclient
```

Comment: Thanks WT_W, your query did the trick, probably it has better performance that do an extra loop, and extra query for each shipment. Until I know, the max of shipments it's like 600 for each search, I guest it's a low charge, but well, I'm going to test your script on my DB of production, to see how it's going. Thanks and if you have andy article to help me understand the hack, I'll be really grateful

Comment: Well now that's a sweet trick. I recently needed to do this without using a user-defined-function in order to list role membership in all databases on the server. I think this will do it...

Comment: @Allende, I can't remember where I picked it up from originally but here are some articles: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ by Anith Sen and http://web.archive.org/web/20150411045033/http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-concatenate-strings-from-a-column-into-a-single-row.html by Aaron Bertrand

Comment: Thanks @WT_W  I'm gonna check ASAP to see If I can learn/understand them

Comment: Here is the specific article source I think Aaron was referring to: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/